# Text Display doesn't save in version 11.1

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I have the problem that my changes to the display style of cells doesn't save with the notebook. When I convert a cell to text-display and check before saving I can see that the style is set as text-display. When I save and reopen the notebook, the cell is back to being an inputform Display. Is there a way to save these cell styles so I won't have to change all the styles every time I open the notebook?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to text-display". Could you give a step-by- step sequence of your actions to convert it? Further, what is the notebook style you work with?

Comment: To convert the cell to a Text Display, I click on the cell bracket on the right, then click on cell in the top bar and select Convert to -> Text Display, which changes the cell from an Input Form to a text Display. Then I click on Save and close and reopen the notebook. After this the cell I changed is back to being an Input form and not a text display. This is in a standard notebook, by just creating a new notebook and then saving.

Comment: Kevin, this your procedure works for me (Min7, Mma 11.1).  The reopened notebook contains converted cells.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this myself and have a partial solution.

It seems that the *Style* of the cell overrides the display properties. So, if the cell's Style is set to "Input", then the display will revert to Input Form.

The partial solution is then to set the Style of the cell to "Text". That way, the display remains as Text Display.

One downside is that the font style is different between Input Style + Text Display, and Text Style + Text Display. The former has a serif font, while the later is sans serif. Also, it doesn't resolve the original issue of *why* the display should revert in the first place.

Comment: Your workaround works, but the problem is still there in versions 13.2, 13.0, 12.3 and 11.3 of Wolfram Mathematica.